# How can I raise an error in my Django form?

Tags: php, json, django, forms

I have a PHP script in a server that returns `{"available":true}` or `{"available":false}`, depending on whether the email address is available or not. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysqlpass";
$dbname = "testdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT username FROM testtable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$query = $_GET['query'].'@groupdesignace.com';
$arr = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[] = $row['username'];
    }

    if (in_array($query, $arr)) {
    $output = array('available' => false);
    echo json_encode($output);
    } else {
    $output = array('available' => true);
    echo json_encode($output);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

On a different server where users are requesting their email address through a form, I am using Django. I have written the following code to check whether the email is available, if not, it should raise an error. Here is the code:

```
class RequestEmailAddressForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email:
            import requests

            payload = {'query': email}
            r = requests.get('http://172.16.16.172/check_email.php', params=payload)
            result = r.json()
            print r.url

            status = result['available']
            if status == False:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This login name is unavailable!')
        return email
```

Here is my view that is handling the form:

```
def request_email_address(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RequestEmailAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            # do something here
        else:
            pass
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/core/home/')
    else:
        form = RequestEmailAddressForm()
    return render(request, "core/request_email_address.html", { "form": form })
```

However, the form is going to the submitted page but it is not raising validation error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your view code

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I did not write a view code yet. The error should generate before the view is run, am I correct?

Comment: No. Validation of form is called by view.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev OK, I added a view. Please check my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing on if form is invalid. When ValidationError is raised django sets `form.errors` dict with data about what went wrong during validation. Read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/

```
def request_email_address(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RequestEmailAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  # <- form validation is called on this line
            data = form.cleaned_data
            # do something here
            # do redirect here
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/core/home/')
        else:
            pass   
    else:
        form = RequestEmailAddressForm()
    return render(request, "core/request_email_address.html", { "form": form })
```

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. It takes the user to a different page and shows the message I pass by doing `return HttpResponseBadRequest('message')`. I want the user to be taken back to the form and show the message over the text field which generated the error, in this case the email field. I have done this with the registration form in the same way where the two passwords didn't match. However, the method is not working here.

Comment: @MiniGunnR It is because this needs to be done in template. It is probably becaues you are redirecting to home instead of rendering errors. Move redirect under `if form.is_valid()`. See my updated answer. Also read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually